# Walletconnect does not stay connected

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, wallet-connect

I am using [walletconnect_dart](https://pub.dev/packages/walletconnect_dart/versions/0.0.3) to connect my app to Metamask. Scanning the QR code or mobile deep link all works well and is immediately connected to the wallet.

The issue I am facing is that when I restart the app, my wallet is no longer connected to the app. Every time I have to reconnect my wallet to the application with a deep link/QR code.

Is there any way to stay connected to the wallet even after restarting the app?

This is how I am connecting to the wallet

```
               final connector = WalletConnect(
                      bridge: 'https://bridge.walletconnect.org',
                      clientMeta: const PeerMeta(
                        name: 'WalletConnect',
                        description: 'WalletConnect Developer App',
                        url: 'https://walletconnect.org',
                        icons: [
                          'https://gblobscdn.gitbook.com/spaces%2F-LJJeCjcLrr53DcT1Ml7%2Favatar.png?alt=media'
                        ],
                      ),
                    );

                    // Subscribe to events
                    connector.on('connect', (session) => print(session));
                    connector.on('session_update', (payload) => print(payload));
                    connector.on('disconnect', (session) => print(session));

                   // Create a new session
                    if (!connector.connected) {
                      final session = await connector.createSession(
                        chainId: 4160,
                        onDisplayUri: (uri) {
                          launchUrl(Uri.parse(uri));
                        },
                      );

                      print(session);
                    }
```

Comment: Hello @hemal, 
Were you able to integrate walletConnect properly in flutter?

Comment: @VivekMakwana Yes

Comment: I have tried the same way as your block of the code, But once the URI is launch in metamask, I don't get connect to wallet option

Comment: And did it work for trust wallet and any other wallet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used [walletconnect_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/walletconnect_secure_storage) package to overcome this issue.

first, initialize the wallet connect storage

```
 WalletConnectSecureStorage sessionStorage = WalletConnectSecureStorage();
```

After that, when you successfully connected with wallet connect (For that I have used [walletconnect_dart](https://pub.dev/packages/walletconnect_dart/versions/0.0.3)), you will get **WalletConnectSession** from the instance of wallet connect

And store **WalletConnectSession** to **sessionStorage** as mentioned below

```
sessionStorage.store(walletConnect.session)
```

After doing this, Your session is successfully stored in **sessionStorage**

Now in **initState** we will get our session from **sessionStorage** and assign it to **walletConnect** instance as mentioned below

```
  final session = await UserDataUtils.sessionStorage.getSession();

    // Create a connector
    walletConnect = WalletConnect(
      bridge: 'https://bridge.walletconnect.org',
      session: session,
      sessionStorage: sessionStorage,
      clientMeta: const PeerMeta(
      name: 'WalletConnect',
      description: 'WalletConnect Developer App',
      url: 'https://walletconnect.org',
      icons: [
      'https://gblobscdn.gitbook.com/spaces%2F-LJJeCjcLrr53DcT1Ml7%2Favatar.png?alt=media'
    ],
  ),
);
```

You can also register listeners

```
walletConnect.registerListeners(onConnect: (status) {
      print(status);
    }, onDisconnect: () {
      print('Disconnect');
    });
```

Comment: I have same code in my project but when I close trustwallet & my app for few minutes, once i am back and try to make transaction using _connector.sendCustomRequest it doesn't show confirmation popup in trustwallet

for metamask it's working fine but TrustWallet session doesn't work